# Como obter data sem hora de DateTime?

Tags: c#, html5

Dentro da variável data eu tenho isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o código em html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly disabled value="@Model.Data">
```

Resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual é a forma mais simples de obter data ? (data sem hora)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matheus,

Utilize o código abaixo para obter a data sem a hora.

```
@Model.Data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Abraço,